# Parsing Excel cells in Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, parsing

Currently in Excel i have a column of IDs and a column of corresponding information in format: {'col1': 'num1', 'col2': 'num2', 'col3': 'num3'}

I need to parse the data and then return a table in excel, keeping the column of IDs and adding col1, col2, and col3 with num1, num2, and num3 in the cells below.

[current format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMaCk.png)

[required format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcpdC.png)

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data is in JSON format. You may want to do is open an Excel file (workbook), read it, use a json library to parse the values in structures, then write it in another Excel file.

To read/write Excel files, you could use [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)+[xlwt](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
To read/write JSON data, you should use [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).